# Start activity from deeplink and on back press resume from latest running activity

Tags: android, deep-linking, intentfilter, deeplink

I am handling deep links in my app. When a link in the email is clicked, it opens related activity in the app. On back press, it either goes back to email or home (up to intent flags i use). 
I need it to go back to **latest running** activity(if the app was being used before clicking the link in email) or(else) go to first activity to restart the app.

To be clearer: User is on **activity C**. Email notification comes, checks it and clicks the link inside. It opens up **activity E**. Here, if user back press, I want to end current task and resume **activity C** - if activity C task has not been killed by the system. If killed, go to **activity A**.

Without intent flags, it creates a new task(second app instance) and on back press it goes back to email client.
With NEW_TASK flag, a new tasks starts. If I use CLEAR_TASK flag with this, on back press it goes home.

Manifest

```
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:scheme="https"
                    android:host="www.mysite.com"
                    android:pathPattern="/mypath/*" />
</intent-filter>
```

FirstActivity

```
if(getIntent().getData().toString().contains("keyword")){
       //intent.setFlags(...);
       intent.putExtra("myextra", getIntent().getData().toString());
   }
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
```

EmailResultActivity

```
 String data = getIntent().getExtras().getString("myextra");
```

Comment: This link will help you https://medium.com/@muratcanbur/intro-to-deep-linking-on-android-1b9fe9e38abd

Comment: Thank you for the link. I have seen it before as well but didn't answer my question. But, I used another way, thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this you need to handle deep-link from a common activity. (Eg: If your app has a common activity say XYZ. Then every deep-link should come to XYZ activity and then according to parameters of deep-link, you should move to respective screen) Also you need to make XYZ as singleTask.

Comment: Thank you, @Jatin. My design is currently like you say but customer side requested it without any mediator activity. But after you answer, I contacted them again and they conceded.